# io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: PERMISSION_DENIED: User not authorized to perform this action

Tags: spring-cloud, google-cloud-pubsub, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-gcp, spring-cloud-bus

I try to implement simple example of `spring cloud config` + `spring cloud bus`.

So I've implemented

1. Client server application
2. Config server application

and in the separated repository I've put [application.properties](https://github.com/gredwhite/config-repo-demo/blob/master/application.properties) file.

Looks like everything is correct on the server side. But on client side I see error when application is starting:

```
org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.BinderException: Exception thrown while building outbound endpoint
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindProducer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:192) ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindProducer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:93) ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractBinder.bindProducer(AbstractBinder.java:139) ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.lambda$rescheduleProducerBinding$2(BindingService.java:267) ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: com.google.api.gax.rpc.PermissionDeniedException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: PERMISSION_DENIED: User not authorized to perform this action.
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptionFactory.createException(ApiExceptionFactory.java:55) ~[gax-1.49.1.jar:1.49.1]
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:72) ~[gax-grpc-1.49.1.jar:1.49.1]
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:60) ~[gax-grpc-1.49.1.jar:1.49.1]
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcExceptionCallable$ExceptionTransformingFuture.onFailure(GrpcExceptionCallable.java:97) ~[gax-grpc-1.49.1.jar:1.49.1]
    at com.google.api.core.ApiFutures$1.onFailure(ApiFutures.java:68) ~[api-common-1.8.1.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$CallbackListener.run(Futures.java:982) ~[guava-28.1-android.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.DirectExecutor.execute(DirectExecutor.java:30) ~[guava-28.1-android.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:1138) ~[guava-28.1-android.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:957) ~[guava-28.1-android.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:748) ~[guava-28.1-android.jar:na]
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$GrpcFuture.setException(ClientCalls.java:515) ~[grpc-stub-1.24.1.jar:1.24.1]
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$UnaryStreamToFuture.onClose(ClientCalls.java:490) ~[grpc-stub-1.24.1.jar:1.24.1]
    at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39) ~[grpc-api-1.24.1.jar:1.24.1]
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23) ~[grpc-api-1.24.1.jar:1.24.1]
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40) ~[grpc-api-1.24.1.jar:1.24.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.CensusStatsModule$StatsClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusStatsModule.java:700) ~[grpc-core-1.24.1.jar:1.24.1]
    at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39) ~[grpc-api-1.24.1.jar:1.24.1]
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23) ~[grpc-api-1.24.1.jar:1.24.1]
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40) ~[grpc-api-1.24.1.jar:1.24.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.CensusTracingModule$TracingClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusTracingModule.java:399) ~[grpc-core-1.24.1.jar:1.24.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:510) ~[grpc-core-1.24.1.jar:1.24.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$300(ClientCallImpl.java:66) ~[grpc-core-1.24.1.jar:1.24.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.close(ClientCallImpl.java:630) ~[grpc-core-1.24.1.jar:1.24.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.access$700(ClientCallImpl.java:518) ~[grpc-core-1.24.1.jar:1.24.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:692) ~[grpc-core-1.24.1.jar:1.24.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:681) ~[grpc-core-1.24.1.jar:1.24.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37) ~[grpc-core-1.24.1.jar:1.24.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123) ~[grpc-core-1.24.1.jar:1.24.1]
    ... 7 common frames omitted
    Suppressed: com.google.api.gax.rpc.AsyncTaskException: Asynchronous task failed
        at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptions.callAndTranslateApiException(ApiExceptions.java:57) ~[gax-1.49.1.jar:1.49.1]
        at com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnaryCallable.call(UnaryCallable.java:112) ~[gax-1.49.1.jar:1.49.1]
        at com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.TopicAdminClient.createTopic(TopicAdminClient.java:256) ~[google-cloud-pubsub-1.101.0.jar:1.101.0]
        at com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.TopicAdminClient.createTopic(TopicAdminClient.java:203) ~[google-cloud-pubsub-1.101.0.jar:1.101.0]
        at org.springframework.cloud.gcp.pubsub.PubSubAdmin.createTopic(PubSubAdmin.java:107) ~[spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.gcp.stream.binder.pubsub.provisioning.PubSubChannelProvisioner.makeSureTopicExists(PubSubChannelProvisioner.java:121) ~[spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub-stream-binder-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.gcp.stream.binder.pubsub.provisioning.PubSubChannelProvisioner.provisionProducerDestination(PubSubChannelProvisioner.java:63) ~[spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub-stream-binder-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.gcp.stream.binder.pubsub.provisioning.PubSubChannelProvisioner.provisionProducerDestination(PubSubChannelProvisioner.java:45) ~[spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub-stream-binder-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindProducer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:174) ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindProducer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:93) ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractBinder.bindProducer(AbstractBinder.java:139) ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.lambda$rescheduleProducerBinding$2(BindingService.java:267) ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
        ... 7 common frames omitted
Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: PERMISSION_DENIED: User not authorized to perform this action.
    at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:533) ~[grpc-api-1.24.1.jar:1.24.1]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
```

Based on stacktrace I thought that problem related with permissions. And to solve it I've granted `owner` permissions:

[image]

But it didn't help for some reason.

Let me share my code base:

[image]

`application.properties` file is empty.

**build.gradle.kts**:

```
plugins {
// For upwards compatibility check
    val springBootVersion = "2.1.0.RELEASE"
    id("org.springframework.boot") version springBootVersion
    ...
}

apply(plugin = "io.spring.dependency-management")
...

group = "my.gcp.samples"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

val developmentOnly = configurations.create("developmentOnly")
configurations {
    developmentOnly
    runtimeClasspath {
        extendsFrom(developmentOnly)
    }
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom(configurations.annotationProcessor.get())
    }
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
// Milestone spring repository
    maven(url = "https://repo.spring.io/milestone/")
}

val springCloudVersion = "Greenwich.RELEASE"
val testcontainersVersion = "1.11.4"
val junitVersion = "5.5.1"

dependencies {
    // GCP bucket
    implementation("org.springframework.boot", "spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud", "spring-cloud-gcp-starter")
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud", "spring-cloud-gcp-starter-storage")
    // GCP big query
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud", "spring-cloud-gcp-starter-bigquery")
    implementation("org.springframework.integration", "spring-integration-core")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot", "spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
    //cloud bus
    implementation ("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-bus-pubsub")
    implementation ("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-client")
}

configure<DependencyManagementExtension> {
    imports {
        mavenBom("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:$springCloudVersion")
        mavenBom("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies:1.2.1.RELEASE")
        mavenBom("org.junit:junit-bom:$junitVersion")
    }
}
```

**Application:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

**ExampleController:**

```
@RefreshScope
@RestController
public class ExampleController {

    @Value("${example.message:none}")
    private String message;

    @GetMapping("/message")
    public String getMessage() {
        return this.message;
    }

}
```

I would like to say that application works partially despite the exception thrown on startup. When I make a `GET` `localhost:8080/message` I see value from file located at the github repository. But if I change this file in the repository then `GET` `localhost:8080/message returns old value.

What wrong with my code ? How to fix it ?

Comment: I guess you are using GCP PubSub to publish Git-backed configuration changes. Is the Config server connecting to a PubSub topic?

Answer (score 2):

I've got the same exception when there was a change in the underlying topic. It worked after I deleted the subscription and created it again with the new topic and gave Subscriber permission in the cloud console page for the service account and then error disappeared.

Comment: you saved my day - similar problem disappeared after I deleted and re-added subscriber permission

Answer (score 0):

I notice in the error message that you need the access to create a new topic:

```
Suppressed: com.google.api.gax.rpc.AsyncTaskException: Asynchronous task failed
        at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptions.callAndTranslateApiException(ApiExceptions.java:57) ~[gax-1.49.1.jar:1.49.1]
        at com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnaryCallable.call(UnaryCallable.java:112) ~[gax-1.49.1.jar:1.49.1]
        at com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.TopicAdminClient.createTopic(TopicAdminClient.java:256) ~[google-cloud-pubsub-1.101.0.jar:1.101.0]
        at com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.TopicAdminClient.createTopic(TopicAdminClient.java:203) ~[google-cloud-pubsub-1.101.0.jar:1.101.0]
        at org.springframework.cloud.gcp.pubsub.PubSubAdmin.createTopic(PubSubAdmin.java:107) ~[spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.gcp.stream.binder.pubsub.provisioning.PubSubChannelProvisioner.makeSureTopicExists(PubSubChannelProvisioner.java:121) ~[spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub-stream-binder-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.gcp.stream.binder.pubsub.provisioning.PubSubChannelProvisioner.provisionProducerDestination(PubSubChannelProvisioner.java:63) ~[spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub-stream-binder-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.gcp.stream.binder.pubsub.provisioning.PubSubChannelProvisioner.provisionProducerDestination(PubSubChannelProvisioner.java:45) ~[spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub-stream-binder-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindProducer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:174) ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindProducer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:93) ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractBinder.bindProducer(AbstractBinder.java:139) ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.lambda$rescheduleProducerBinding$2(BindingService.java:267) ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
        ... 7 common frames omitted
Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: PERMISSION_DENIED: User not authorized to perform this action
```

First, I'd like to clarify:

1. How you pass your credentials? The following snippets will show how you can set a service account authentication:

```
ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(<Service-account-as-string>.getBytes());
CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider =
      FixedCredentialsProvider.create(
          ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(byteArrayInputStream));


TopicAdminSettings.Builder topicAdminBuilder = TopicAdminSettings.newBuilder();
if (credentialsProvider != null) {
  topicAdminBuilder.setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);
}
TopicAdminClient topicAdminClient = TopicAdminClient.create(topicAdminBuilder.build());
```

2. If you're using service account, you can check whether your service account is allowed to create a new topic.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had missed adding pubsub editor role to my topic. After adding it solved issue for me.
Take a close look at permission tab and add necessary pincipals.

[image: sample principals]